# Find all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_6\times \mathbb{Z}_6$ containing the diagonal $\{(a, a) \mid a\in\mathbb{Z}_6\}$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, direct-product

My question is exactly the one written in the title.

My first idea was to find the subgroup lattice of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_3$, and separate the once containing the diagonal $\{(a, a) \mid a\in\mathbb{Z}_6\}\simeq\mathbb{Z}_6.$ But, it feels like there should be a more systematic way of doing this.

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem could help narrow this down. You need $6\mid \lvert H\rvert$ and $\lvert H\rvert\mid 36$ for all such groups $H$.

Comment: That's assuming the diagonal subgroup is a subgroup of $H$ though. I believe it should be by the one-step subgroup test . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the group $G$, and the diagonal $D$. Then $D$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and so there is a bijective correspondence between subgroups of $G$ containing $D$, and the subgroups of the quotient $G/D$. Note that $G/D$ is an abelian group of order $6$, and so $G/D\cong\mathbb{Z_6}$. So it follows that there exactly $4$ such subgroups.

And now note that for each divisor $d$ of $6$ there is such a subgroup:

$H_d=\{(a,b)\in G: \text{$a-b$ is divisible by $d$}\}$

Check that $H_d$ is well defined, and is a subgroup containing $D$. So these are the $4$ required subgroups.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation.

Comment: For abelian groups, I can see that, $G\times G/D$ is isomorphic to $G.$ Is it true always?

Comment: @Bumblebee You mean $G\cong D\times G/D$? This is not always true even for abelian groups. For example, $\mathbb{Z_4}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$, though it has a subgroup of order $2$ whose quotient has order $2$ as well. In my answer, I only used the fact that $G/D$ is an abelian group of order $6$. And in general every abelian group of order $6$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_6}$. You can also find an isomorphism directly. The map $f:G\to\mathbb{Z_6}$ given by $f(a,b)=a-b$ is a well defined surjective homomorphism, and its kernel is $D$. Hence $G/D\cong\mathbb{Z_6}$.

Comment: I meant $(G\times G)/\text{diag}(G\times G).$ Exactly the homomorphism in your comment shows this is isomorphic to $G.$ But for non-abelian groups that map is not a homomorphism. I am thinking of the generalization of my question for all finite groups.

Comment: If $G$ is nonabelian, then $D$ is not a normal subgroup of $G \times G$, so the question does not make sense.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, you are right.

Comment: But it still makes sense to ask for the subgroup between $H$ and $G \times G$. For example, if  $G$ is simple, then $D$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$.